# Tracking actions like selecting a checkbox

Tags: google-analytics, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have some check boxes on my website selecting which the data on the page gets filtered but the page name remains the same. I want to capture the data for visitors selecting any of the check boxes. Can you please let me know how can this be done?

Presently, I have different page name whenever the user select any of the check box. But by doing this, Page views data for that page becomes irrelevant.

Comment: What have you tried? Why did you add google=analytics tag? How is this related to GA?

Answer (score 1):

For Omniture tracking, that's very possible, but you need to add a bit of javascript.  You need to add an onClick event for the checkbox, and have it submit a custom link event to Adobe.  They provide a function for it:

```
s.tl(this, 'o', 'Checkbox X Clicked');
```

Prior to this call, you can set props/evars if you want other tracking tied to this event.  It doesn't count as a page view, though.

The Omniture implementation guide is here:

http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/oms_sc_implement.pdf... do a search for the s.tl() function.  It'll explain.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your page has JavaScript that does the filtering.

You would need to add to this JavaScript to send an AJAX request to the server every time the user makes their selection.  The server will need to track the requests in a database or a file.  After that, you can analyse the results.

There are many ways to send AJAX requests in JavaScript.  The basics are here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp but there are also 3rd party libraries available.

Unfortunately there is nothing that "google-analytics' can do for you here, as far as I know.

Good luck,
DC